# How to hide or solve Tensorflow warning about TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

When running a program in which Tensorflow is used, the following warning is printed:

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:39] Overriding allow_growth setting because the TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH environment variable is set. Original config value was 0.

I am trying to get rid of this warning. The reason is because I'm running this program from another Python file, so now the warning shows up in the results that are returned to that file. I have tried several things to hide or resolve the warning, however they have resulted in nothing more than reducing the amount of times this warning is printed from 4 to 1. What I'm now doing is including 'os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'' (which should cause no warnings or errors to be printed), as well as including 'os.environ['TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH'] = "true"' (also tried 'True' and '1'), and importing 'warnings' and wrapping all the code in 'with warnings.catch_warnings():' and including 'warnings.simplefilter( "ignore" )'.

I'm quite sure the rest of my code is working properly, so I just want to get rid of this warning, or resolve it in a suitable way.

Comment: Just to make sure. Are you certain that you had os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3" executed before any TensorFlow command? Because for me, when I put it at the beginning of the file, it removed all warnings regarding "Overriding allow_growth".

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of Tensorflow warnings include this piece of code in your main script.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```